# How do I take maps, and combine their keys into a vector of maps?

Tags: clojure, etl

I have data like this:

```
[{:a [{0 0}
     {2 2}
     {9 9}]}
 {:b [{2 2}
     {5 6}
     {7 7}]}
 {:c [{0 1}
     {5 5}
     {5 3}]}]
```

and I want to transform it to be like this:

```
[{:a {0 0}
  :b {2 2}
  :c {0 1}}
 {:a {2 2}
  :b {5 6}
  :c {5 5}}
 {:a {9 9}
  :b {7 7}
  :c {5 3}}]
```

Basically, take the first element of (get :a m), (get :b m), (get :c m) and make that a new map, then take the second element of (get :a m) , (get :b m), (get :c m) and put that into a second map, etc. It's sort of taking a map of vectors and transforming it into a vector of maps.

Restriction, can only use clojure.core.

What I've tried - The most promising idea I have is taking `(flatten (mapv keys data))` and `(mapv vals abc)` and combining the data somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the values, this looks like a transpose.  And then you want to zip
the result back together with all the keys.

```clj
(defn transform
  [ms]
  (let [firsts (map first ms)
        keys (map key firsts)
        vals (map val firsts)
        transposed (apply map vector vals)]
    (mapv (partial zipmap keys) transposed)))
```

Naming it is up to you.

For golfing, you can also get the keys and vals by transposing:

```clj
(defn transform
  [ms]
  (let [[keys vals] (->> ms
                         (map first)
                         (apply map vector))]
    (mapv (partial zipmap keys)
          (apply map vector vals))))
```

Comment: How did you know this needed to be transposed? What was your thought process?

Answer (score 1):

I like @cfrick approach. Yet another threading approach (not that elegant imo though)

```
(->> (apply merge data)
     (map (fn [[k xs]] (map vector (repeat k) xs))) 
     (apply map vector)
     (mapv (partial into {})))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to collect each inner pair into a record containing the index and key and then re-shape those into the output structure you want:

```
(defn transform [ms]
  (let [rs (for [m ms
                 [k ps] m
                 r (map-indexed (fn [idx p] {:k k :p p :index idx}) ps)]
             r)
        gs (->> rs (group-by :index) (sort-by first) (map second))]
    (mapv (fn [rs] (into {} (map (juxt :k :p) rs))) gs)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that using functions that operate on lazy sequences, such as [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) and a few more. The [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) is a threading macro and is often used to compose operations on collections and lazy sequences:

```
(defn reshape-data [input]
  (let [fe (map first input)
        ks (map first fe)]
    (->> fe
         (map second)
         (iterate (partial map rest))
         (take-while (comp seq first))
         (map #(zipmap ks (map first %))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to re-write the code, you can use 2 functions already in the [tupelo.csv](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.03.04/api/tupelo.csv) library to switch between attribute-oriented format and entity-oriented format.  A quick demo using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.csv :as csv]))

(def orig
  [{:a [{0 0}
        {2 2}
        {9 9}]}
   {:b [{2 2}
        {5 6}
        {7 7}]}
   {:c [{0 1}
        {5 5}
        {5 3}]}])

(verify
  ; Quick transform into a "attribute-oriented" matrix (or just edit manually)
  (let [attrs (into {} orig)]
    (is= attrs
      {:a [{0 0} {2 2} {9 9}]
       :b [{2 2} {5 6} {7 7}]
       :c [{0 1} {5 5} {5 3}]})

    ; Transform into a "entity-oriented" matrix
    (let [entities (csv/attrs->entities attrs)]
      (is= entities
        [{:a {0 0} :b {2 2} :c {0 1}}
         {:a {2 2} :b {5 6} :c {5 5}}
         {:a {9 9} :b {7 7} :c {5 3}}]))
    ))
```

The [source code](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/v23.03.04/src/clj/tupelo/csv.clj#L41) is very straightforward.